# Problem plotting two spatial maps together using ggplot and geom_sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to plot two sf objects together using ggplot and geom_sf. I am able to plot the objects separately but not together as a single map. crs of both the sf objects is the same. Attached code and output below.

1.
`ggplot()+ geom_sf(data=final_data_sf)`

[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifdkw.png)

2.
`ggplot()+ geom_sf(data=ward_boundaries)`

[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJULN.png)

3.Plotting 1 and 2 together
`ggplot()+ geom_sf(data=ward_boundaries)+ geom_sf(data=final_data_sf)`

[Plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgEvP.png)

Comment: The 2 sf objects are very far apart from each other. `final_data_sf` has essentially a latitude of 0°; whereas, `ward_boundaries` has a latitude of 40°. So, it is essentially zooming way out in order to capture both of them, and the default is to just fit to size. So, you could adjust the x and y axes, and mess with the aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

The latitude numbers look a little strange on you final_data_sf map.  I would guess in the process of constructing that sf object you speciefe the wrong field as your latitude input, or otherwise manipulated your lat column.

Comment: I created the final_data_sf object by transforming a data frame containing the latitude and longitude details using st_as_sf function. I also provided the same crs as ward_boundaries object, when transforming the dataframe to the sf object. #fetch crs of ward boundaries# the_crs <- st_crs(ward_boundaries)  #convert the data frame to an sf object, having the fetched crs#final_data_sf <- st_as_sf(final_data_cleaned, coords=c("latitude","longitude"),crs=the_crs)

Comment: During the conversion to sf you would want the crs to be in the projection of the data you are bringing in, which is usually 4326 with lat/long data, also when specifying co-ords it is x,y so long then lat, try ```final_data_sf <-st_as_sf(final_data_cleaned, coords=c("longitude","latitude"),crs=4326)``` then make sure crs are the same with ```st_transfrom(final_data_sf, crs=the_crs)```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have been able to plot the map using the above steps.